# Can I make a timer run until my user is finished fetching data?

Tags: sharepoint, timer, powerapps

A page in my Power App shows a gallery populated from a filtered SharePoint List. My workplace's internet connection is terrible, so my team is worried that the gallery might not be fully populated if the user has network issues while the gallery loads. Our current fix is to run a timer on the page (set to a fixed and arbitrarily high amount) forcing the user to wait before they can click on any item in the gallery.

Is there any way to force a timer to run until all data has been loaded in to the gallery from a SharePoint List?

Answer (score 0):

You could instead of populating the data into the gallery directly set up a collection (clearcollect) that contains the items and show them in the gallery (I.e. in the onvisible property of the screen). Than you can simply change editability in the function that creates the collection in the next Code line. Or turn a variable true and false that shows a loading gif before and after the collection creation. Make sure if you want to edit an item though to patch the „real“ item and not the one on your temporary collection (via lookup). Hope it’s clear